# Using fuctions in C

Tags: c

Basically I'm trying to make a program that you enter 4 x,y coordinates into 1 at a time and after each one that you enter it verifies that the entry is valid (a number) and if it isn't it sends an error message. Then if all 8 numbers are valid, it checks whether the 4 coordinates form a rectangle. I have both parts of the code done but my question is, how do I make a function for the first part, that you enter 2 numbers into 4 times and then take THOSE valid numbers and send them to my next function for verifying the rectangle. This is what I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
//verifying point validity
int main(void)
{
int x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4;

printf("Enter point #1:\n");
if (scanf("%d%d", &x1,&y1)==2)
{
    goto two;
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid Entry\n");
}
two:
printf("Enter point #2:\n");
if (scanf("%d%d", &x2,&y2)==2)
{
    goto three;
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid Entry\n");  
}
three:
printf("Enter point #3:\n");
if (scanf("%d%d", &x3,&y3)==2)
{
    goto four;
}
else
{
    printf("Invalid Entry\n");
}
four:
printf("Enter point #4:\n");
if (scanf("%d%d", &x4,&y4)==2)
{
    goto next;
}
else
{
printf("Invalid Entry\n");
}
next:






}

//function for verifying rectangle

static bool IsRectangle(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2,
                   int x3, int y3, int x4, int y4)
{
x2 -= x1; x3 -= x1; x4 -= x1; y2 -= y1; y3 -= y1; y4 -= y1;
 return
 (x2 + x3 == x4 && y2 + y3 == y4 && x2 * x3 == -y2 * y3) ||
 (x2 + x4 == x3 && y2 + y4 == y3 && x2 * x4 == -y2 * y4) ||
 (x3 + x4 == x2 && y3 + y4 == y2 && x3 * x4 == -y3 * y4);
}
```

So I just want to know how I can use the function for checking the rectangle work to return "This is a rectangle" or "This isnt a rectangle"

Thank you!!

Comment: Please do not use `goto`

Comment: As a side note, your gotos do absolutely nothing.

Comment: what stopped you from calling your function with input arguments after taking and validating all the inputs?

Comment: Avoid using `goto` statements!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to call the `IsRectangle()` function, just add the following code between the `next:` and `}` lines:

```
if (IsRectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4))
{
  printf("The points define a rectangle.\n");
}
else
{
  printf("The points do NOT define a rectangle.\n");
}
```

However, as others have pointed out, there are a few other problems with your code:

- There is no `return` statement in your `main()` function - it should return an `int` as specifed in the declaration. More specifically, it should return zero to indicate that the program ended without problems.
- The `goto` statements aren't doing anything to protect against invalid entries. The `else` code sections will cause `printf("Invalid Entry\n");` to be triggered, but the code will then continue on to the next section anyway. Also, [GOTO statements make Edsger W. Dijkstra sad](http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html).
- You've got almost the exact same code copy-pasted four times, one for each point.

I'd recommend re-factoring your "point input" code into a `for` loop, with the x/y values stored in arrays for simplicity:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    int x[4];
    int y[4];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    {
        printf("Please enter point %d: ", i+1);
        while (scanf("%d %d", &x[i], &y[i]) != 2)
        {
            printf("Invalid point, try again: ");
            while (getchar() != '\n') { /* Wait until RETURN is pressed. */ }
        }
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Alternatively, you could move the input logic into a separate function that is then called four times by `main()` to get each point.